# Do path mappings work between different projects that are being referenced?

Tags: javascript, typescript, yarnpkg, tsc

I am having trouble getting path mapping to work between two different typescript projects in a yarn workspace setting.

I have 2 different projects in a yarn workspace. so the folder structure is as shown below.

```
packages
├── common
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   └── logger.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── main
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   └── settings.ts
│   │   └── main.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
tsconfig.base.json
node_modules
```

In my tsconfig for /main I have

```
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "Common/*": ["../common/src/*"]
    },
    "references": [
    { "path": "../common","prepend": true }
  ]
```

In main/src/main.ts I am trying to import a default export from the module like so

```
import Log from 'Common/logger'
```

but I am getting the error:

> TS2307: Cannot find module

This is not something I have ever had an issue with using typescript, so I am wondering if the issue has to do with the fact that the path I am attempting to map to is also being used as a project reference.

I am expecting this to work as it normally does, Being able to import `../common/src/logger` as `Common/logger`.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue in this situation turned out to be that I am extending from `tsconfig.base.json`, which does not have the key "paths" set inside of it. Basically, inheritance in tsconfig files work exactly like in oop, and I was attempting to override a field that did not exist in the base config.

The fix was to simply add

```
    "paths": {
      "Common/*": ["./packages/common/src/*"]
    }
```

inside of `tsconfig.base.json` and everything works.